# In phpMyadmin, why is password "user_122" and "user_124" accepted, but "user_123" is not for accessing a database?

Tags: phpmyadmin, passwords

In phpMyAdmin I am setting up databases and connecting users to them. I found I can give users passwords of "user_122" and "user_124", but not "user_123". That seems to be strange. Why?

Comment: They must have very simple and stupid password rules. Why would you even want to have such a weak password?

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it still does not answer the question. The phrase "user_" could have been anything (i.e., "15ka6$a@ftkmN"). However, in this case I used it to ask a simple question, namely why are "122" and "124" ok, but "123" is not?

<br/>
The reason for my post -- I created a password generator that appended various words together from different dictionarary and symbol arrays and also appended a random number between 1 and 999, but found I had to create an exception for any password that contained the phrase "123". I was wondering the logic of  that?

Comment: 123 is considered too simple by whatever the script logic is. 122 has no apparent pattern.